# Accept only some variables in form fields from CSV and not all in Django?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django model with 2 fields as latitude and longitude. I've declared them both as a CharField. My model needs to accept more than 1 coordinates (latitude and longitude), so while entering in the rendered form (in the UI), I'm entering these coordinates separated by commas. It's this char input which I'm then splitting in the function and doing my computations..

This is my models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=1000,help_text="Add the latitudes followed by comma")
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=1000,help_text="Add the longitudes followed by comma")
```

This is my view.py function

```
def dashboard(request):
    form = LocationForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            latitude = list(map(float, form.cleaned_data.get('latitude').split(',')))
            longitude = list(map(float, form.cleaned_data.get('longitude').split(',')))
            .........
            .........
    return render(request, dashboard/dashboard.html, { 'form':form })
```

Now, I want my model to accept the coordinates as a CSV file too. I want an option in the UI to add a CSV file (having multiple latitudes and longitudes) which then populates these two char fields (as comma-separated values).

Note that, my CSV file won't have the country name. I shall be entering the country using the form UI only.

Thus, in short, I need to accept some of the form fields as CSV file and not all.

I found solutions uploading the CSV file but they all populate all the model fields instead of just selective. So there's a dependency that the CSV file must contain all the form field values (in my case, country too)

What can I do? Maybe, have a FileField() in the model and do something with that.. Or maybe I can just use javascript to populate the coordinates in the UI.. or maybe something else..

Not sure what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers

Then for your form class:

```
# import csv
# import codecs
# form = LocationForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('file', 'country', 'latitude', 'longitude')  # this order matters

    def clean_file(self):
        if 'file' not in self.files:
            return

        file = self.files['file']
        reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(file, 'utf-8'))
        header = next(reader)
        latitudes = []
        longitudes = []
        for lat, long in reader:
            latitudes.append(lat)
            longitudes.append(long)
        self.data['latitude'] = ','.join(latitudes)
        self.data['longitude'] = ','.join(longitudes)
        return file
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that any validation you have for `clean_latitude`/`clean_longitude` will still work.

Here are my tests if you get stuck: https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/64a8ec7dd023f2195316c38b15c5ebbd#file-csv_upload-py-L143

---

A couple of thoughts:

1. Models are singular in django, rename `Countries` -> `Country`
2. Why does latitude/logitude have to be `CharField`s? Can't they be decimal places? You already have the relationship correct from `Location` to `Country` (see #1), meaning you can have multiple `Location`s for a single `Country`, why cram all geo points into a single row?

*Personally*: I would remove the `CharField` from both longitude and latitude, and change the type to `DecimalField`. Run validation on each of the fields, and the csv file upload would loop over each of the rows and create a new `Location` instance per each of the country-longitude-latitude combination.

I should state, I do not know the reasons for why you're doing what you're doing and I am 100% speculating.